# File Removing And Renaming Error

Tags: c, file-io

I'm learning C and I'm trying to rename and remove a file. This is my code :

```
    fclose(satis);
    if(!remove("satis.txt"))
        printf("file deleting error\n");
    fclose(gecicisatis);        
    if(!rename("gecicisatis.txt", "satis.txt"))
        printf("file rename error\n");
```

This is header of my .cpp file :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<conio.h>
```

There isn't any error while debugging . But it's output is :

```
file deleting error
file rename error
```

If you need this is my whole code : http://pastebin.com/kNY0y2xz (line 157 to 162)

This is our homework so i have to use a txt file. I have to solve **why file removing and removing returning error.** Can you help me for just solve this problem ?

Comment: Use `perror`: `perror("file deleting error");` and `perror("file rename error");`

Comment: What is the path to the file that you're trying to modify? Are you sure that you have appropriate permissions to modify that file? I notice that you're including `<windows.h>`, which implies that you're running Windows. On Vista and later, UAC will most likely prevent you from modifying files at the root level of your hard disk, which might have seemed like a good scratch space for testing purposes.

Comment: perror's output is blank . It's not printing anything.

Comment: @CodyGray , it's Windows 7 . I'm using Visual Studio 2010 . I'm using same header files and functions (rename() and remove()) on my another project. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

Zero value is returned if the file is deleted or renamed **successfully**.

---

You have to change your check to:

```
if( remove("satis.txt") != 0 )
    printf("File deleting error\n");

if( rename("gecicisatis.txt", "satis.txt") != 0 )
    printf("File rename error\n");
```

Comment: I'm checking folder and files still there . It's not removed.

Answer (score 0):

`remove` returns `0` on success. So you need to reverse your condition in `if`. Also whenever you encounter an error condition it is better to call the function `perror` which will print the cause of the error:

```
if(remove("satis.txt"))
   perror("File deletion failed\n");
```

And same is the case with the function `rename`.

Since you are providing only the file name and not path name, it is assumed that the file exists in the directory from where the executable was launched (assuming you are not changing the pwd of the process). If this is not the case you'll have to pass the pathname, which can be either relative or absolute.

Comment: I'm checking folder and files still there . It's not removed / renamed

Comment: Make sure the file is not open by any other process.

Comment: (answer to your edit) i'm creating file with `fopen("file.txt", "w");` so it's creating file to same directory with .exe file. And then i'm trying to remove it with `remove("file.txt");`so i think it's same directory. There isn't problem.